# Power 12v DC actuator when 120v @15 amp saw is switched on

Tags: relay, switching, 12v

**Problem**: I want to use a 12v DC actuator to close a blast gate on my dust collecting system when I turn on a 120v 15 amp saw. The actuator can only run for a few seconds until the 6" stroke is reached. If there is a way to close the actuator when the saw is turned off that would be a bonus.  Otherwise I will have to have 2 sets of these controls; one to open and one to close when not needed.

I originally thought I could use a current switch to sense the current at the saw switch. I couldn't find the output info of the current switch to know where to go from there. I then thought I could use a time delay interval relay, but am not finding relays where the input is 120v @15 amp and output is 12v DC. I find them the other way though. I have looked at contactors which seem to be 120v in 120v out and I would lose the time delay function. I believe there has to be a way to do this with minimal devices. I would like to do this with off the shelf devices where I don't have to built a circuit board. Lastly, I would like to do this for $50 or less or so.

Comment: Relays don't have output voltages, they have dry contacts. You supply the power through a power supply, through the relay, to power the device.

Comment: You will have to draw a diagram with inputs Dual or bipolar switch? for open close. High side switch or low side and exact time duration then current or resistance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for this to work you need to be sure that your actuator has end stop switches what will cut the power upon reaching the end of stroke, even when power to the motor is maintained. You could use a 4PDT relay with 12VDC contacts and 120VAC coil and wire the contacts in a H-Bridge design to the actuator. You can google How to wire a H-Bridge switch to give you an idea how this is done. You will need a separate 12VDC power supply for the actuator. You then wire the coil to the saw so that when the saw is powered the relay is also powered. When the relay is energized the actuator will move in one direction and when the relay is off it will move in the other direction.

If your actuator does not have end stop switches you will need a current limiting device or motor controller, such as a TR-EM-208 card. These can be adjusted to turn off the power when the actuator reaches the end stroke and caused a spike in motor current. You would only need a SPDT relay if you used a motor controller as you are only switching the control signal to the motor controller.

Comment: Wow, this seems complicated for a person who doesn't know about this. I am not sure if there are limit switches. Details don't say. I asked about that waiting on reply.

Comment: Is the  4 pole DT relay to operate the actuator both ways? I understand the reason for the h bridge wiring to operate the actuator in both directions. Seems like this is wired to the 4poles of the 12v side of the relay. One set of poles for the positive motor and the other 2 poles for the negative/reverse rotation. After knowing the terms, this conceptually makes sense to me. 

Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: Yeah thats correct, the 4 poles are just to allow for the H-Bridge circuit. You sound like you have your head around it now and how it all fits together.

Comment: I find 120v @ 15amp coil relay but I don't see where the congrats are rated. Is it safe to assume that as long as the coil fairing is right the other contacts will handle 12v dc?. If not can you agar a link to buy one?. Thanks for help on this.

Comment: This looks like what I need.  https://www.thermaldevices.com/product/4pdt-four-pole-double-throw-ice-cube-relay-120-vac-coil-15-amp-rated/?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIm8_rv6-Q7gIVCfHACh1pIwSNEAQYASABEgIuT_D_BwE

Comment: Yes that one look like it will work 

Comment: I have a working prototype of the relay, h-bridge, actuator.   Now I am thinking about scaling this to many saws in my shop to control the same blast gate via the same relay.  My plan was to add a wire at each saw's motor to the relay.  When the saw turns on the relay will energize, but so will all the other saw motors even if the saws are switched off.  Then I thought I would wire it into the switch but I don't have access to some of the switches.  Question is how can each saw power the relay without powering each saw, or am I thinking about this wrong?  Thank you for your help!

Comment: thoughts on the previous comment of mine?

Comment: Hi Chris,  there is not really an easy way i can think of to do it with relays. You are right about your relay feeding back power to the other saws. I originally thought individual relays might work but that is not the case. That H-bridge design was very simple in that there is always power at the actuator and it relies on the actuator end stop switches to stop the motor.  If you have other relays sending power to the actuator the situation could arise where they create a short between the different relays and you would just blow a fuse on your power supply.

Comment: You could keep that relay powering the actuator and get individual relays for each saw, single pole relays would do. So the coil of these individual relays is connected to the saw so they are powered at the same time that the saw motor comes on. The contacts of the individual relays are connected to the coil on the actuator relay, so it is controlled by the individual saw relays. That way one saw can be on and it not feed power back to the other saws, also you don't have to worry about the problem mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks Ben, this is what I came up with too. I think I will do it with a contactor though only because they are cheaper. Do you see any issue with using a 120v coil 120v rated contacts contactor?

Comment: Hi Chris, no there wouldn't be any problems with that. Good luck with it.

Comment: Great. Keep checking back, I will post the final product once done. Thanks for sharing your knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6wOZn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Pending confirmation specs of your Actuator.

Answer (score 1):

@Ben G here is my final product which is working like a champ with your help.

[image: Automatic blast gate brain]

Bottom right corner is a 120v coil contactor connecting to a bus bar. Out of the bus bars 120v goes to the relay. On either side of the relay are 120vac to 12vdc transformer, 1 per motor/blast gate. I have 1 blast gate open when a machine comes on and one close when the same machine comes in. This allows for the dust collection trunk the machine is on the most CFM air flow while the other trunk is closed.

Comment: Blast gates working https://home.mycloud.com/action/share/a26cda64-8dc5-460d-9e29-8dbcbdd93b69         https://home.mycloud.com/action/share/bad7c173-5b2e-4a7a-b641-601efad2445c